# Is it correct to write: "what does a writer, a soldier and, a tourist guide have in common?"

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

I have a question regarding the correctness of the following sentence:

> What does a writer, a soldier and, a tourist guide have in common?

Should I use *do* or *does*?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: “A writer, a soldier, and a tourist guide” are *they*. What do *they* have in common?

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence

> What does a writer, a soldier and, a tourist guide have in common?

should be written as

> What do a writer, a soldier, and a tourist guide have in common?

"Do" is appropriate since you are referring to "they", and the comma should be moved.

> What do *they* have in common?

It possibly sounds like the beginning of a bad joke... :)